# how to insert current time automatically in table in oracle forms?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a problem in oracle forms. 
My database is consisting of a main table,table name is (buy_order_customer) which has (b_order_id,customer_id,b_date,b_time).

I'd like to insert the current  time automatically in the b_time column, I'm able to insert the current date in the b_date column but I can't do the same with b_time.

Both b_date, and b_time is of type 'date'.

can any one help please?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you alter your **b_time** column to TIMESTAMP?  Also, what error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle DB a [`DATE` datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330) **always** contain both date and time (even if you don't display them.

So, if you inserted the current date into b_date then you already have the current time as well.

Try this:

```
SELECT to_char(b_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  FROM buy_order_customer
```

and see that you have the time as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the initialvalue to fill these fields in a form at runtime.
If I'm right then you need one of the following system variables:

$$DATE$$ retrieves the current operating system date (client-side).

$$DATETIME$$ retrieves the current operating system date and time.

$$DBDATE$$ retrieves the current database date.

$$DBDATETIME$$ retrieves the current date and time from the local database.

I don't know any system variable to retrieve only the time.
If it is for displaying purposes you need to use dateformat masks on your fields.